# Why does this $R_0$ exist?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading [Conway's complex analysis book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) and on page 116 he writes:

[image]

I didn't understand why such $R_0$ exists.

Comment: Take $R_0=-\ln(\epsilon/3\pi)/\sin\delta$, which is always defined.

Answer (score 1):

$e^{-t}$ is a strictly decreasing function with $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}e^{-t} = 0$. Therefore for fixed $0 < \delta < \epsilon/3$ (assuming $\epsilon$ small) we have that $e^{-R\sin\delta} = e^{-R c},$ where $c$ is a positive constant, and clearly such an $R_0$ exists. The fact that $\delta$ is chosen so that $\delta < \epsilon/3$ is so that in the previous line you will get
$$
2\delta + \pi exp(-R\sin\delta) < \epsilon.
$$